# Stop users pushing to stable branch in mercurial

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-hook

I'm just starting to use Mercurial as a source control system. I was thinking of using the workflow similar to the one outlined here: http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/05/mercurial-workflows-stable-default/. Basically, have two branches, one 'Stable' and one 'Development'. All development will be done on the 'Development' branch, and only merged into the 'Stable' branch when tested and ready for release.

```
o | v2.0
|\|
| o added new feature
o | V1.0
|\|
| o added new feature
| |
| o fixed bug
o |
```

I want to stop developers from accidentally pushing changes to the stable branch. How can I achieve this? I know there are ways of hooking into certain Mercurial events, but which one could reject a push if it made changes to the stable branch? And how can I detect that changes have been made in certain branches within a hook?

I'm running Windows 7 by the way.

## UPDATE

Thanks to criswel for his answer - it pointed me in the right direction. Turns out the ACL extension (which comes with mercurial) solved this problem. I edited the 'hgrc' file in the main repo's '.hg' folder to look like this:

```
[extensions]
acl = 

[hooks]
pretxnchangegroup.acl = python:hgext.acl.hook

[acl]
sources = push

[acl.deny.branches]
stable = *
```

This stops anyone from making changes to the stable branch and pushing them to the main repo.

Comment: It's a tricky subject. We create branches off of branches and then, through bitbucket create pull requests that act as an approval layer from which the changes are then merged down into the primary branch from which they were created from. You can prevent users from doing anything to the main branches, but not selectively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is the [ACL extension](https://mercurial-scm.org/wiki/AclExtension), which should be included in your install of Mercurial.

Comment: @criswelll thanks for your answer - this pointed me in the right direction! The detailed solution is now included in my question.

Comment: The link has changed.  Here is the current link to the [ACL Extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/AclExtension)

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use the [mercurial-server](http://www.lshift.net/work/open-source/mercurial-server/) third-party extension to Mercurial (it is more a wrapper around Mercurial) to manage developers access rights. However it might be more difficult to setup on Windows as it would require using Cygwin.